# How to print shell variables and values to be able to copy/paste them?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, escape-characters, variable

In Bash 4.2.25, the `set` and `env` output is not escaped, so shell escapes and any non-printable characters won't be copy-pasteable. Take for example this shell session:

```
$ export foo=$'a\nbar=\baz'
$ env | grep -A 1 foo
foo=a
baraz
```

Ditto for for example colors - They are printed literally, and can mess up the terminal. **How do you print all variables with their values in a way that the output can be copied and pasted to give the same environment?***

* Obviously with the standard caveats about readonly variables, special variables like `$_` and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
printvars() (
  eval 'declare() { printf declare; printf " %q" "$@"; echo; }'"
        $(declare -p)"
)

printvars
```

That could be easily extended to omit read-only variables like:

```
printvars() (
  eval 'declare() {
          [[ $1 = *r* ]] && return
          printf declare; printf " %q" "$@"; echo
        }'"
        $(declare -p)"
)
```

Comment: Redefine `declare` in a subshell to print its own output. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
escaped_env() {
    cat /proc/self/environ | while IFS== read -r -d '' name value
    do
        printf '%s=%q\n' "$name" "$value"
    done
}
```

Example session:

```
$ export foo=$'a\nbar=\baz'
$ escaped_env | grep foo
foo=$'a\nbar=\baz'
```

This works, but only for `export`ed variables, and `set` doesn't seem to have a ␀-separator option.

FYI, the /proc filesystem is not a [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) feature, and it looks like only [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) implements `/proc/self/environ`. If your OS doesn't have this file, you may want to use `env --null` before the pipe.

Comment: If your `env` does not support `--null` but you're on Linux, you can use `cat /proc/self/environ` instead.

Comment: It looks like `/proc/self/environ` is not updated when exporting more variables.

Comment: Hence the use of `cat` (which in this case is not a UUOC) to pass that updated environment along the execution of a new command.